# Git search history and show diff

Tags: git

`git log -G` searches history for diffs containing an expression, but it only outputs the commit message for each diff found.

Is there a way to do this but also output the actual content of the diffs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the -p option:

```
git log -p -G mysearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's `git diff`.  Try reading the instructions for that (`man git-diff`).

You could use the commit ids and filenames to compare particular things, a la:

`git diff <commit_id> <filename> <other_commit_id> <filename>`

That'll show you the diffs of the files given at the time of the commits specified.

Comment: True, though `git log` doesn't show the relevant filenames either, or the id of the commit before or after the one it found; doubtless there are ways to find these things using other commands and finally construct a `git diff` command, I was just hoping there might be something a little more automated.